# Prompting an input in bash script should executes an bash function

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I would like to get an output based on the input we provided. For Example,

if I selected `1` it should take the 1st element in the array and the output should be `My name is test`

if I selected `2` it should take the 2nd element in the array and the output should be `My name is test1`

similarly, if I select `all` the output should be `My name is test
My name is test1
My name is test2
My name is test3`

```
 a=("test" "test1" "test2" "test3")

testfunction() {
        echo My name is $a
}

echo "Enter a number"
select number in "test" "test1" "test2" "tes3" "all"; do
    case "$number" in
        test)
            testfunction "${a[0]}"; break;;
        test1)
            testfunction "${a[1]}"; break;;
        test2)
            testfunction "${a[2]}"; break;;
        test3)
            testfunction "${a[3]}"; break;;
        all)
            testfunction "${a[@]}"; break;;
    esac
done
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Why do you need a separate case for _number_ in 1,2,3,4? Just verify that if `$number`  is numeric and in the correct range, and then call `testfunction "${a[$number]}"`.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by other answers, you should use `$1` in your `testfunction()`.
Additionally, you can use a for loop to get your desired output when you select `all` as your input.

```
a=("test" "test1" "test2" "test3")

testfunction() {
        echo My name is $1
}

echo "Enter a number"
select number in "test" "test1" "test2" "test3" "all"; do
    case "$number" in
        test)
            testfunction "${a[0]}"; break;;
        test1)
            testfunction "${a[1]}"; break;;
        test2)
            testfunction "${a[2]}"; break;;
        test3)
            testfunction "${a[3]}"; break;;
        all)
            for i in "${a[@]}"; do testfunction "${i}"; done
            break;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be printing `$1` instead of `$a` in your `testfunction`.

```
testfunction() {
        echo My name is $*
}
```

EDIT: Changing it to consider "all" case as well.

Comment: It is only taking the first element in the array even if I enter the ```all``` in the prompt.

Comment: My bad.... I didn't consider "all" case. Use `$*` instead of `$1`.